# Javascript - Access object node with variable as concatenated string

Tags: javascript, string, object

Is it possible to access an object node with the node path in a variable?

Consider this object:

```
var myObject = {
    settings: {
        some_key : 'some value'
        some_other_key : 'some value'
    }
};
```

And i've got this string:

```
var model = 'settings.some_key';
```

With this data, i want to get the value of `myObject.settings.some_key`.

If it was just a single "node" in the variable (for example `settings`, i could access it with `myObject[model]`, but i can't get that working when i need to go multiple levels into the object (first `settings` then `some_key`.

---

**Edit:** I was unclear in my initial question. What i actually want to do is *write* to the object, not read. I want to change the value of `myObject.settings.some_key` to something, not just access it, as i previously stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `model` value based on `.` and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the split array, like this

```
console.log('settings.some_key'.split(".").reduce(function(result, currentKey) {
    return result[currentKey];
}, myObject));
# some value
```

To set the value, you can do something like this

```
var dataToBeSet = "some other value;"

'settings.some_key'.split(".").reduce(function(result, currentKey, index, array) {
    if (index === array.length - 1) {
        result[currentKey] = dataToBeSet;
    }
    return result[currentKey];
}, myObject);

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Hmm, this works for getting the value, but not setting it. `currentKey` gives me the actual value of the node, not the key name, and `result[currentKey]` is undefined. I tried to simplify the question by stating i wanted to *get* the value, but what i actually need to do is *set* the value. *EDIT:* `result` is always the same as `myObject` for me.

Comment: @qwerty But that is an entirely different question :-)

Comment: You're right. Any pointers? What i'm trying to do is put some JSON data from localStorage into actual objects.

Comment: @qwerty Can you please edit your question to add the information about adding data to the object as well?

Comment: Of course, see edit. It's really the same except i'm writing instead of reading from the object.

Comment: @qwerty Sorry, I rollbacked the edit. Because, to the people who see my answer now, it would be completely inappropriate. Please include the new question, without modifying the old contents.

Comment: I really can't get it to work with my code. `result` is always undefined. I copied the relevant bits over to JSFiddle, please see if you can find anything wrong, because i really can't see anything that differs except for variable names. http://jsfiddle.net/9yXfK/

Comment: @qwerty Aren't you missing the `return` statement in the `reduce`'s callback function?

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Don't know how i missed that. I got it working perfectly, thanks!